# Holder regularity for solutions to the Poisson equation

Tags: nonlinear-analysis, poissons-equation, holder-spaces

I am dealing with a nonlinear PDE of the form
$$-\Delta u=f(u),\quad in\,\,\,\mathbb{R}^n$$
(where $f(u)$ is a nonliear function)
I would like to ask you which regularity results do exist in the case when $f\in C^{0,\theta}$.
Thank you!