# $C^2$ regularity for $-\Delta u$ Hölder?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, holder-spaces

If $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ is such that $- \Delta u$ is $C^{0,\alpha}$, then do we have $u \in C^{2,\alpha}$ ?

The regularity theory I know tells me that
$$
u \in \bigcap_{1 < p < \infty} W^{2,p}(\Omega) \subset \bigcap_{0 < \alpha < 1} C^{1,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)
$$
from which I do not know how to go further. For instance
$$
\bigcap_{1 < p < \infty} W^{2,p} \nsubseteq W^{2,\infty}
$$
so I need better regularity theory. In case $\alpha = 0$, I know examples of
$$
- \Delta u \in C^0(\bar \Omega) \nRightarrow u \in D^2(\Omega)
$$
*i.e.* a function whose Laplacian is uniformly continuous but which is not twice differentiable everywhere. I do not know it these examples can be adapted to to Hölder regularity.

Actually this question arised when I was studying the problem of a strong solution of
$$
-\Delta u = f(u)\text{ on } \Omega,\quad u = 0 \text{ on }\partial \Omega
$$
being a classical solution. In this setting an obvious necessary condition is $f$ continuous. A sufficient condition is $f \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$, in this case it is standard to show by regularity theory that
$$
u \in \bigcap_{1 < p < \infty} W^{2,p}(\Omega) 
$$
and the superposition theory for Sobolev function tells us that
$$
f \circ u \in \bigcap_{1 < p < \infty} W^{1,p}(\Omega) 
$$
so that using the same regularity theory
$$
u \in \bigcap_{1 < p < \infty} W^{3,p}(\Omega) \subset \bigcap_{0 < \alpha < 1} C^{2,\alpha}(\bar \Omega).
$$
This can be slightly weakened to
$$
f \in \bigcup_{1 < p_0 < \infty } \bigcap_{p_0 < p < \infty} W^{1,p}(\mathbb R)
$$
but I don't know how to relax the differentiability condition, for instance $f$ Hölder continuous. In this case the superposition theory for Sobolev functions fails but it's not clear that the regularity of $u$ also fails because as it is a solution of an elliptic PDE I hope it is more regular than "any Sobolev function".

This question is linked to [Holder regularity for solutions to the Poisson equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397935/holder-regularity-for-solutions-to-the-poisson-equation)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can conclude that $u$ is $C^{2,\alpha}$. If $v\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ then Schauder estimates tell us that for any $\Omega’\subset \subset \Omega$, $$ \| v\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega’)}\leqslant C(\|\Delta v\|_{C^\alpha(\Omega)}+\|v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}). $$ The constant $C$ depends only on $n$, $\alpha$, $\Omega’$, and $\Omega$.

Since $u$ is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and not $C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$, we apply Schauder to a mollification of $u$, $u_\varepsilon$, to obtain \begin{align*}
 \| u_\varepsilon\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega’)}&\leqslant C(\|\Delta u_\varepsilon \|_{C^\alpha(\Omega)}+\| u_\varepsilon\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)})\\
&\leqslant C(\|\Delta u\|_{C^\alpha(\Omega)}+\|u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}).
\end{align*} Moreover, since $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $\| u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leqslant C \| \Delta u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$, so \begin{align*}
 \| u_\varepsilon\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega’)}&\leqslant C\|\Delta u\|_{C^\alpha(\Omega)}.
\end{align*} Taking $\varepsilon \to 0$, gives the result.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas, I have two questions. 1) How do you know from $u \in H^1_0$ that you can control $\| u \|_{L^\infty}$ with $\| \Delta u \|_{L^\infty}$? In my lecture notes it is said that in general $-\Delta : H_0^1 \cap W^{2,\infty} \rightarrow H^{-1} \cap L^\infty$ is not an isomorphism. 2) How do you conclude from the boundedness of $(u_\epsilon)$ in $C^{2,\alpha}_{loc}$?

Comment: For 1: This is a well known inequality - normally it is stated as if $\Delta u =f$ in $\Omega$ then $\| u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leqslant C \| f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$, see https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf Lemma 1.14. This is not the same as $-\Delta : H^1_0 (\Omega)\cap W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)$ being an isomorphism because the norm on $H^1_0 (\Omega)\cap W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)$ is not $\|\cdot \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$

Comment: For 2: This is a property of mollifiers. If $\{ u_\varepsilon\} \subset C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega’)$ and $\|u_\varepsilon\|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega’)} \leqslant M$ then $u\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega’)$ with $\|u\|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega’)} \leqslant M$, see https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf#page39 Section 1, (H8)